# Getting exception in JQuery file uploader

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, jhipster

I am new to JQuery file uploader and I am implementing some part of that.  When I select an image from JQuery file uploader, a call goes to server side (SpringController) but the API returns:

> 406 Not Acceptable

this my call to server:

```
$(this).fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: uploadSettings.upload_url,
        type: 'POST',
        maxNumberOfFiles: uploadSettings.maxNumberOfFiles,
        maxFileSize: uploadSettings.maxFileSize,
        acceptFileTypes: uploadSettings.fileSelection,
        sequentialUploads: true,
        paramName:'uploadfiles[]',
        dataType: 'text'
    });
```

and my Java Controller code is as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/user/fileuploader" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, 
produces = "text/plain")


@ResponseBody public String uploadFileHandler(
@RequestParam("uploadfiles[]") MultipartFile[] file,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Any advice?

Comment: Your backend service is telling that the response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept-Type HTTP header in your Client request. Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

1.Find out the response (content type) returned by Service 2.Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code -> 406

Comment: You mean need to describe content-type:'multipart/form-data' with url. and response which i have return from controller is text/plain text which i have describe in data:'text'. and my accept type is "Accept text/plain, */*; q=0.01"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that uses a very similar stack to JHipster (I'm the author of both projects), and which does uploading with the same JQuery plugin:

https://github.com/ippontech/tatami/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/ippon/tatami/web/fileupload/FileController.java#L193

As you can see my return object is different. You can copy my code from:

https://github.com/ippontech/tatami/tree/master/src/main/java/fr/ippon/tatami/web/fileupload

Comment: Thanks for reply..but i am using .html page so i unable to use jstl tag.

Comment: the pages go to 404. do you have new urls?

Comment: The original reffered: https://github.com/ippontech/tatami/blob/90fdbfc474dca03ede431460237a80f8e442cbe3/web/src/main/java/fr/ippon/tatami/web/fileupload/FileController.java#L193